# What's with all the junk information in my exe file?

Tags: c, exe

I made a very simple program using dev c++ v5.11 (in c language), and I wanted to take a look at the compiled code in HxD to see how it compares to the original code. The problem is that around 95% of the compiled information looks like junk information, and it seems to have taken a 9 line code and stretched it out to a 127 kb file, with many null spaces, error handling strings, and a section with many type declarations, in string format. My question is, why is this a thing, and what other program could I use to just compile the code to be as long as it needs to be?

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int count = 0;
    start:
        count = count + 1;
        printf("count is %d\n", &count);
        goto start;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled code is too large to be put in the body

Comment: The code includes debugging information?

Comment: You have a huge header file sitting top of your code.

Comment: is there any way to reduce the size of the header, like include only printf?

Comment: Build without debug information. No a lot you can do about the C runtime.

Comment: Try without `printf("count is %d\n", &count);`.

Comment: @DradenMerenox: Yes, you can omit the bulk of `stdio.h`. Per C 2011 7.1.4 2, you may declare the function yourself instead of including `stdio.h`. Delete `#include <stdio.h>` and insert `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`. This will omit any declarations that occur in `stdio.h`, other than `printf`. However, during linking, your use of `printf` may still cause significant portions of the standard library to be linked into your executable.

Answer (score 2):

Any complete answer will be specific to your compiler, and the manner in which you have built your program, and the host system.   I'll focus on the generic concerns.

Compiling with debugging information and without optimisation (often the default settings of a compiler) will result in a lot of extra information in your executable.   And, there are also link options, such as related static versus dynamic linking, which control how much information from a library is copied into the executable (with trade-offs of executable size, reliance on libraries being accessible at run time, etc, etc).

There may also be utilities on your system (e.g. strip under unix) to remove some unneeded information from an executable.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this article interesting, which attempts to get the smallest possible executable size, for a Linux executable: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

I imagine the majority of your executable is taken up with code from the stdio.h include.

You also might be interested in the looking at the assembly output, rather than looking at it in HxD, which you can get with the /fa switch in visual studio. You can find this setting under Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Output Files.